# System.AccessViolationException with Dynamic Proxy Generation

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp, access-violation

We are using PostSharp to inject caching functionality, we are only seeing this issue when we are using it. When we use Spring the issue seems to go away.

Any help would be appreciated as this, the issue is very difficult to replicate. I've included the stack trace below:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. 
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. 

at System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore.SymWriter.CloseMethod() 
at System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder.CreateMethodBodyHelper(ILGenerator il) 
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock() 
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType() 
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.BuildType() 
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateCode(Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options) 
at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxy(Type theClass, Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options) 
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type targetType, Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArgs, IInterceptor[] interceptors) 
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type targetType, Type[] interfaces, IInterceptor[] interceptors) 
at NHibernate.Proxy.Poco.Castle.CastleProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
```

Comment: Similar: http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/DYNPROXY-129

Comment: Similar: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rhinomocks/WaapfXGTh-E

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar probelm which I resolved by configuring:
Application Pools -> Advanced Setting ->'Enable 32-Bit Applications' to True

Restart IIS and WebSite.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a similar recurring problem with the project I'm working on, which makes heavy use of Rhino Mocks.

It happens in .NET 3.5 on 64-bit machines when mocking a large number of different interfaces.

The .NET 4.0 beta doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: Has a cause been found for this issue?

Comment: In our case, we just edited our build script to run our separate test assemblies separately to reduce the number of dynamically-instantiated types per test run, which reduced the probability of the issue. We then later simply upgraded to .NET 4.0 which seemed to solve it entirely.

My guess is it was probably some bug in the unmanaged code in MS reflection methods.